# How to deploy keycloak on kubernetes with custom configuration?

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak

I want to deploy keycloak with below custom configuration, before starting it.

- new realm
- role
- client
- an admin user under the new realm

I am using below deployment file to create keycloak pod

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: keycloak
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:10.0.1
        env:
        - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
          value: "admin"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
          value: "admin"
        - name: REALM
          value: "ntc"
        - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
          value: "true"
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/jboss/keycloak/startup/elements
          name: elements
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
        - name: https
          containerPort: 443
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /auth/realms/master
            port: 8080
        volumes:
      - name: elements
        configMap:
          name: keycloak-elements
```

and using below cilent.json and realm.json file to generate configmap for keycloak.

**client.json**

```
{
  "id": "7ec4ccce-d6ed-461f-8e95-ea98e4912b8c",
  "clientId": "ntc-app",
  "enabled": true,
  "clientAuthenticatorType": "client-secret",
  "secret": "0b360a88-df24-48fa-8e96-bf6577bbee95",
  "directAccessGrantsEnabled": true
}
```

**realm.json**

```
{
 "realm": "ntc",
 "id": "ntc",
 "enabled": "true",
 "revokeRefreshToken" : true,
 "accessTokenLifespan" : 900,
 "passwordPolicy": "length(8) and digits(1) and specialChars(1)",
 "roles" : {
  "realm" : [ {
        "id": "c9253f52-1960-4c9d-af99-5facca0c0846",
        "name": "admin",
        "description" : "admin role",
        "scopeParamRequired": false,
        "composite": false,
        "clientRole": false,
        "containerId": "ntc"
    }, {
      "id" : "1e7ed0c8-9585-44b0-92f8-59e472573461",
      "name" : "user",
      "description" : "user role",
      "scopeParamRequired" : false,
      "composite" : false,
      "clientRole" : false,
      "containerId" : "ntc"
    }
   ]
  }
}
```

Both the files are saved under the `elements` folder and used in the below command to generate the config map:

```sh
kubectl create configmap keycloak-elements --from-file=elements
```

Still, I don't see any new realm/role or client created in the [KeyCloak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXf97.png) console.

Comment: How did you get / generate the client.json and realm.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to import the realm and client like described here http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/keycloak/keycloak-with-docker

Some environment variables might help to accomplish the task.

Comment: using the deployment.yaml file, I am able to set the admin user and password. so I hope I could similarly configure the custom realm as well. I am aware of the procedure mentioned in that link.

Comment: @SiddhantaRath Exactly. And you can also set KEYCLOAK_IMPORT to point to your configmap files e.g. realm.json

Comment: now I am changing some parameter at configmap file and re-deploying the changes at Kubernetes, sadly, it is not reflecting under the realm setting

Comment: @SiddhantaRath did u get any solution??

Comment: @Brucewayne-TheGeekKiller yes, used KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=/tmp/realm.json as env variable at deployment file mentioned at the question

Comment: @SiddhantaRath could you post your working deployment file so we can see how it all fits together please?

Answer (score 1):

When you are setting up Keycloak on kubernetes, you only need to import the new realm (realm.json) and the corresponding clients (client.json) only during the first run. So a **Job** needs created instead of adding it to the deployment.

Once the Job is run, the json will be imported to the Keycloak database and the job can be suspended. Adding it to the deployment will cause Keycloak to try and import the json files during each restart.

Please follow the steps in this blog post: https://blog.knoldus.com/migrate-keycloak-h2-database-to-postgres-on-kubernetes/